# how to make an html page show in a frame in gwt

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

My project is organized like this:

I have a gwt frame in my main html page (shuttle_website_2.html)

there is a folder in the `war` folder.... `path war/Assets/Animation/airport_shuttle_animation.html`

so in the gwt-frame url I put this `Assets/Animation/airport shuttle animation.html` and it works fine in hosted mode.

When I deploy it to appengine it says:

```
 Error: Not Found

The requested URL /Assets/Animation/airport%20shuttle%20animation.html was not found on this server.
```

How do I make the html page show up in the frame after it is deployed to appengine?

Here is the appengine-web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>reservationtransport1</application>
  <version>1</version>

  <!-- Configure serving/caching of GWT files -->
  <static-files>
    <include path="**" />

    <!-- The following line requires App Engine 1.3.2 SDK -->
    <include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="0s" />

    <include path="**.cache.*" expiration="365d" />
    <exclude path="**.gwt.rpc" />
  </static-files>

  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>

</appengine-web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the file or folder is being excluded from GAE.  Check your appengine-web.xml (often located in war/lib).

appengine-web.xml docs:  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html

Less likely (because it probably would have shown up in hosted mode), perhaps the web.xml file or the framework you are using isn't serving it out.

[EDIT]
Or, you also seem to be using spaces in one place and underscores in another.

One more debugging hint: Try accessing the html file just from the browser, e.g. http://reservationtransport1.appspot.com/Assets/Animation/airport%20shuttle%20animation.html

Comment: here is the appengine-web.xml